# Работа в Arduino через Python

Tags: python, arduino

Юзаю Arduino Uno, при запуске кода светодиод на плате мигает несколько раз, затем гаснет и при этом никаких действий плата не выполняет. К ардуине подключён драйвер шагового движка и соответственно к драйверу движок. Из под Arduino IDE всё работает отлично без каких либо проблем. Код:

```
import pyfirmata
import time

board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM3')
board.digital[8].write(1)

while True:
    board.digital[5].write(1)
    time.sleep(1)
    board.digital[5].write(0)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: я до этого туда просто пустой скетч залил что бы плата ничего не делала

Comment: Так если пустой скетч прошит, который не понимает протокола firmata, то плата никак и не будет реагировать.

Comment: @insolor спасибо залил фирмату там права другие странности пошли но двигатель работает